# Access object using an indexed object type annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to pass a parameter when opening a modal container with the component that should be rendered in the modal.

I have an enum and I want to access the object with component and title based on a value from the Modals enum
I know that in enums, the values sent are numbers so I made Dict type.

```
export enum Modals {
    INVITE_NEW_USER,
    EDIT_USER,
    DELETE_CLASS,
    DELETE_STUDENT,
    BLOCK_STUDENT,
    ADD_NEW_CLASS, 
    CLASS_PROFILE,
    EDIT_CLASSROOMS,
    ADD_NEW_USER_TO_CLASSROOM
}

export const MODAL_TYPES =  {
    ADD_NEW_USER: {component: InviteNewUserModalComponent, title: "Add New User"},
    DELETE_CLASS: {component: DeleteClassModalComponent, title: "Delete Class"},
    DELETE_STUDENT: {component: DeleteStudentModalComponent, title: "Delete Student"},
    BLOCK_STUDENT: {component: BlockStudentModalComponent, title: "Block Student"},
    ADD_NEW_CLASS: {component: AddNewClassModalComponent, title: "Add new class"},
    CLASS_PROFILE: {component: ClassProfileModalComponent, title: "Class Profile"},
    EDIT_CLASSROOMS: {component: EditClassroomModalComponent, title: "Edit Classrooms"},
    ADD_NEW_USER_TO_CLASSROOM: {component: AddNewUserModalComponent, title: "Add New User"},
    EDIT_USER: {component: EditUserModalComponent, title: "Edit User"},
}

export type ModalType = 'INVITE_NEW_USER' | 'EDIT_USER' | 'DELETE_CLASS' | 'DELETE_STUDENT' 
                        | 'BLOCK_STUDENT' | 'ADD_NEW_CLASS' | 'CLASS_PROFILE' | 'EDIT_CLASSROOMS'
                        | 'ADD_NEW_USER_TO_CLASSROOM';


export type Dict = { [key: number]: any };
```

The problem is in my component, when I try to access an object from MODAL_TYPES I get undefined

```
  @ViewChild('modalContent', {
    read: ViewContainerRef
  })
  modalContent!: ViewContainerRef;
  public modalTypes: Dict = MODAL_TYPES;
  public modal!: ModalType;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public modalType: any,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.modalType) // output: number 0-7
    console.log(this.modalTypes[2]) // output: undefined


    this.modal = this.modalTypes[this.modalType].title;

    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.modalTypes[0].component); // modalTypes[0] is undefined

    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.modalTypes[this.modalType].component); // also undefined
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the type assignments are incorrect, and the wrong keys are being used to access the values

```js
// expects object with number format keys
export type Dict = { [key: number]: any }

// MODAL_TYPES has string keys e.g. "ADD_NEW_USER"
public modalTypes: Dict = MODAL_TYPES

// You're then trying to get keys e.g `1` when there's no keys like that in the object
this.modal = this.modalTypes[this.modalType].title;
```

There's a number of ways to resolve this - maybe remove the `Dict` type which isn't really needed, and look at a using the enum as keys and for key/value object lookup